# How do I build this query in yii2; myField like "firstname%lastname"

Tags: yii2, builder

I have been using the Query builder in Yii2. When trying to make a filter like this:

```
      where myaddress like 'avenue%12%espe'
```

When I tried this:

```
andWhere('like','myaddress', 'avenue%12%espe')
```

The constructor detect % caracter and inserts escape wildcards automatically and ignores them, help please

Regards

Comment: [Use DB Expression (not recommended on user inputs)](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression)

Comment: @InsaneSkull there is more safe https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-conditions-likecondition